# How to install additional Gimp fonts

Tags: 13.04, fonts, gimp

I want to install more text fonts on Gimp. Currently I have only the default fonts.

Where can I download and install them?

I am on Ubuntu 13.04, using gnome - lastest version.

Comment: See [How to add new fonts to gimp?](http://askubuntu.com/q/320791/58950)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

All you need to do is: add the fonts that you want to Ubuntu, and then you can use them in Gimp.

Download the font(s) that you like, and once downloaded, you can double click on the font file, and that will open Font Viewer, just click on install, and you're done.  Take a look at [Dafont](http://www.dafont.com/) for a great selection of fonts.

[image]

To download, just click on the download button.

[image]

Once you click download you will see the image below, just click OK.

[image]

Double click the font, and that will open the Font viewer, as shown above, just click on Install.

[image]

Comment: I would like to add how to install the fonts from that website. When I will be able to add a new font, I will mark this answer. Thanks!

Comment: Just added it to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, it works! +1, because you are a Firefox fan like me. :-)

Answer (score 18):

For some reason, on Ubuntu 19.04 + GIMP 2.10 after installing the font in Ubuntu it did not appear in Gimp, not after restarting Gimp, nor restarting the system itself. What solved the problem was to copy the .TTF font file to one of GIMP fonts directory. Font directories can be managed in `Edit > Preferences > Directories > Fonts` menu. In my case, that directory was `/home/snap/gimp/227/.config/GIMP/2.10/fonts`.

Comment: This might be a tickle-point, but for me this is under Edit > Preferences > Folders > Fonts.

Comment: I guess the move to snap is the problem here: isn't that a sandboxed environment; which presumably makes accessing system files less straightforward?

Answer (score 3):

in general

- TTF go to `~/.local/share/fonts/TTF/`
- OTF go to `~/.local/share/fonts/OTF/`

for gimp only

- `~/.gimp-2.8/fonts/`

[see docs](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-using-fonts.html)

Comment: I am using Gimp 2.10 and my gimp font directory is `~/.config/GIMP/2.10/fonts`

Answer (score 2):

I use Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS with Gimp 2.10.

Gimp was first installed as snap.

Just installing the fonts didn't work.

Past the font files to directories Gimp knows fonts are availables didn't work.

I had to go in Ubuntu Software, uninstall Gimp (the snap version).
Then re-install Gimp by command line :

```
    sudo apt-get install gimp
```

Then the normally installed font just worked fine.

I only get problems since snap are used in ubuntu.